# incompatible shapes when using tf.keras.layer.add() layer in keras residual block

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

Hello been trying to make a NN using keras functional api using a residual block after running the function "get_new_Yolov3_model()" i get an error as follows

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[51], line 1
----> 1 model = get_new_Yolov3_model(input_shape_Yolov3, 1e-5, 0.15)
      2 model.summary()

Cell In[50], line 39
     36 net = BatchNormalization()(net)
     37 net = LeakyReLU()(net)
---> 39 outputs = resblock(net, 32)
     41 model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="Yolov3")
     43 lr_schedule = 0.001

Cell In[50], line 15
     12 net = BatchNormalization()(net)
     13 net = LeakyReLU()(net)
---> 15 out = Add()([shortcut,net])
     17 return out

File e:\Programes\Anaconda\envs\DirectML-YoloV3-TF2\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
...
     77             )
     78         output_shape.append(i)
     79 return tuple(output_shape)

ValueError: Inputs have incompatible shapes. Received shapes (206, 206, 64) and (204, 204, 64)
```

the code for the nn is as follows

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, BatchNormalization, LeakyReLU, Add

def resblock(input, filters):
    shortcut = input
    net = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size=(1, 1))(input)
    net = BatchNormalization()(net)
    net = LeakyReLU()(net)

    net = Conv2D(filters * 2, kernel_size=(3, 3))(net)
    net = BatchNormalization()(net)
    net = LeakyReLU()(net)

    out = Add()([shortcut,net])

    return out
    
def get_new_Yolov3_model(input_shape, wd, rate):

    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape)

    net = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), kernel_initializer='random_normal', strides=1,
            bias_initializer='zeros', input_shape=(input_shape), name='Input_Conv')(inputs)
    net = BatchNormalization()(net)
    net = LeakyReLU()(net)

    net = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), kernel_initializer='random_normal', strides=2,
            bias_initializer='zeros')(net)
    net = BatchNormalization()(net)
    net = LeakyReLU()(net)

    outputs = resblock(net, 32)
    
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="Yolov3")

    lr_schedule = 0.001

    opt=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = lr_schedule)

    los=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
    acc=tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()

    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=los, metrics=[acc])

    return model
```

i think the issue is caused by conv2d not having proper parameters but i don't know how to exactly solve it

i tried changing the filter size for conv2d but it always seemed short in by 2 in dimentions

Comment: You need `padding=same`.